# MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride execute 3 times slower on windows server 2016 vs windows 10 pro

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-server-2016

I have been working on determining why our WPF application runs approximately 3 times slower in our production environment than it does on our local machines. I have been using one of our blades that we use in production to test various changes to settings to try to get the same times. We finally switched the OS from Windows Server 2016 to Windows 10 Pro and the application runs just as fast on the blade as it does on my local machine.

After doing some profiling using dotTrace remotely I was able to determine that the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride are taking more time to execute on 2016 than they are on 10. We switched the server to prefer desktop applications over background processes and their was no change in execution time. Also we have not overriden any of the Measure or Arrange methods. We are using infragistics for some of our controls so they more than likely have override these.

Does anyone know of a setting or implementation detail of Windows Server 2016 that could account for such drastic changes in execution time?

Edit:
We have also tried installing a graphics card, enabling RemoteFX, optimizing a specific form to have less redraws. Also I just went ahead and profiled a WPF application with almost nothing on it and using dotTrace it takes 8ms to do the measure locally and 750ms to do the measures on our server.

Here is the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StockWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StockWpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Text" Height="20" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="20" Width="50"/>
</Grid>
```

2016 Profiling:
[image: 2016 Profiling]

10 Pro Profiling:
[image: 10 Pro Profiling]

Comment: How are you testing/accessing the application you are running on your Blades? Is it via Remote Desktop connections?, or by local logons. It could be something to do with that. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae95f1c9-c67e-4950-b01f-d3f7fa0408e4/wpf-performance-via-remote-desktop-increased-performance-after-installing-visual-studio?forum=wpf ... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop/

Comment: ....failing that you could use the WPF Performance Suite to analyze how you app is behaving with the GPU on the differen editions of Windows .......https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2015/01/16/new-ui-performance-analysis-tool-for-wpf-applications/ - or use the one built into Visual Studio 2015. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2015/01/16/new-ui-performance-analysis-tool-for-wpf-applications/ ....maybe there is a difference in the available texture memory, etc.

Comment: We have performed all tests through RDP. I have looked into optimizing our WPF to cause less redraws and optimized one location to use less complex containers and any optimizations I made were reflected on 2016 and 10. I installed visual studio as well just to see if it would have the same results this user reported and it did not.

Comment: It's probably something to do with the RemoteFX protocol used in RDP then - maybe there have been some new optimizations added.

Comment: We had the RemoteFX feature installed at one point and it made no difference in times.

Comment: WPF can run using different tiers depending on the GPU hardware that is available etc. See if you can check if it's fallen back to "CPU software" rasterization instead of the higher GPU one.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf/.   As a "test" you could set your app to use Tier 0.....i.e. use CPU rasterization. Then compare the speed on both OS's.....this would give you a baseline. If they are the same, then that gives you a clue. As you up the Tier level, if they widen in performance, that gives another clue.

Comment: I had set the app to display its tier on a label and it has been 2 and 0 based on whether the GPU was installed and RemoteFX was installed. We have been removing and putting back in a GPU to see if it made any difference and it actually slowed down performance by approximately ~5% which was even more baffling.

Comment: run the WPF Performance suite, that should show you what is taking the time on the rendering thread. Do you have animations? Perhaps, you could reduce the FrameRate. Also you want to see if the FrameRate being achieved is different on each OS. http://mrpfister.com/journal/wpf-rendering-performance/

Comment: @ColinSmith thanks I will look into the frame rate and see what I can find I haven't run into that yet. We disabled many of the animations in our WPF application when we detect we are running on a terminal server and I turned off all the graphics features I could from the advance properties of the machine itself.

Comment: You haven't got some automation tools installed on that 2016 Server have you? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6c4465e2-207c-4277-a67f-e0f55eff0110/poor-wpf-application-performance-due-to-ui-automation-on-certain-machines?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation ....are they fresh installations of both 2016 and Pro 10 ?

Comment: They are fresh installs but I am using UIA to run tests on both machines.

Comment: Also are you using the same locales. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635982/wpf-textblock-measuring-is-4-5-times-slower-for-non-english-text-comparing-to-english-one .... do you have any other differences between the 2016 installation and Windows 10 Pro? .....e.g. ClearType on/off ?

Comment: They are the same locales but I am not sure about clear type I will have to check that.

Comment: and are you using same "theme" on both OS's

Comment: Yeah they are both using the default theme, just double checked them.

Comment: ClearType is on, on both machines as well

Comment: On your "slow" profiling screenshot, it shows that Textformatting took 200ms...the other one doesn't even mention it....so maybe something to do with the text rendering. Are you using and got the same font on both systems? Perhaps run this benchmark app, so see if they have the same performance. Would rule out something funky in your application....maybe help isolate issue. https://github.com/dgrunwald/WPF-Text-Rendering-Benchmark

Comment: I will give that a shot, thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you have the PresentationFontCache service running on both machines. Also maybe watch the CPU usage in that process in task manager (or Process Explorer). https://highransom3060.jimdo.com/2016/06/24/the-case-of-the-mysterious-presentation-font-cache-cpu-hog/ ... then you could try disabling that service on both machines, and see how they compare.   .... https://www.infopackets.com/news/10039/how-fix-disable-presentationfontcacheexe-high-cpu

Comment: It was not running on the server. I am turning it on to see if it has any affect.

Comment: Turning that service on and off seemed to affect no affect on either machine. The CPU usage is ok for both machines. The application is about 15% of the CPU on my local machine and 4-5% on the blade. The font cache was not using any CPU on my local machine and was disable on the server so was using no resources.

Comment: I ran the benchmark application you linked me and the best performance was GDI on 2016 which produced ~60 OnRender calls but on the 10 Pro machine I got ~850 OnRender for GDI. This does explain why our VB6 application doesnt seem to suffer as badly when running on the servers though. WPF was getting ~30 OnRender calls on 2016 and ~60 on 10 Pro using the TextBlock.

Comment: Check out the Windows Experience Index on both OS's - if they differ widely then that could provide your answer. Perhaps on Windows 2016...it's using a different driver for the Graphics Card, or some other bottleneck is occuring.

Comment: One final thing...make sure you are using the same Power Profiles on both OS's. When you installed Server 2016 which "role" did you originally choose?..was it File Server? Try and make sure you are using the High Performance Power Option.

Comment: https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/windows-power-plans-and-cpu-performance/ .... run the Geekbench Performance....and you can then see the true underlying performance of both systems under each OS.

Comment: Our power options were set to balanced, if you submit the power options as the answer I will accept it as soon as I can. @ColinSmith I can thank you enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered there was a difference in the "Power Plans" you were using in Windows 10 Pro, and Windows Server 2016.

After installation of Windows Server, the default Power Plan used might not be optimal depending on what you are getting your Server to do.

RDP'ed desktops running GDI or WPF rendering based apps appear to perform poorly when Balanced Power Plan is in use.

(depending on support....newer or older generations of CPUs might also have different latency issues when switching between the power states when Balanced mode is in operation).

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/11/10/windows-server-2012-file-server-tip-switch-to-the-high-performance-power-profile/
- http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/windows-power-plan-effects-on-newer-intel-processors/

Comment: I thought I would also add this to Colin's post since we ran into this when moving to our VMWare machines and trying to get the power setting changed for them https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018206